# Is there a way to get Android Market on galaxy s?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-play-store

How can I get the android market on a Galaxy S on on the Turkish carrier Turkcell. I think that Google's absence in Turkey as a tax paying entity may be why the android market is missing.

Is there a way of sideloading the android market? If not, can you direct me to a ROM that does (preferably Gingerbread)?

P.S. It have 2.1 installed, and the phone model number is GT-i9000

Comment: Where are you located? Who is your carrier? Specifically which flavor of Galaxy S?

Comment: Saying you have a "Galaxy S" is like saying you have a "HP Pavillion" because there numerous iteration of the Galaxy S with different specs, different carriers, different network technologies, different versions of the UI, running different versions of Android...  When asking for help **ALWAYS** include: Phone model, Android Version, Cell Provider (if applicable) and it's usually helpful to say what country you are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android Market **is** on the Galaxy S, it's a Google-approved device.

**Edit:** Since you aren't on Froyo already I recommend getting it through Kies Mini, download from: http://samsung.com/uk/.  That should have the Market since it's not through your carrier.  You have a GT-i9000, so you could also try a JPX-based ROM like this one: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=854799

Comment: @Sveki: I don't know of any case where Matthew Read is not correct.  Clearly there is something else going on with your phone but you have provide far too little information for anyone to even guess at the problem.  If you want more specific and relevant answers you need to provide more specific and relevant information about your problem.

Comment: @Sevki I own a Galaxy S, in fact I am posting from it.  Perhaps you installed a bad ROM.

Comment: @matthew this is not a by google phone it has a android buy on the back no google logo... its a thing about carriers...

Comment: @Sevki I didn't say it was the official Google device like a Nexus.  Google-approved devices get to have the Market, they have to pass a series of tests.  Of course a carrier could influence the bundled software though.  As Matt says, we need more detail.

Comment: thanks matthew, sorry for the questions format it was a bit unclear

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a carrier specific issue.  Try the solution suggested [here](http://www.teknolojiherseyim.com/samsung-galaxy-s-market-yuklemek-en-son-ve-kesin-cozum/) or [here](http://www.teknolojiherseyim.com/samsung-galaxy-s-turkcell-rom-a-market-yukleme/).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that you have backed all of your data up, because the next process **WILL HARD RESET YOUR CELL**. There will be no rooting or anything in the following steps.

1. if your phone is set to 12 hours format, alter your settings back to 24 hours format (Settings-->Date and Time--> check 24 hour format)
2. Go to your keypad, as if you are going to dial a number, then dial *#272*XXXX# PLEASE MIND that those Xs are not letters they represent time, for example if it is 23:15 then you dial *#272*2315#
3. right after the previous step, and without hitting any key,  you will get some options after that, make sure you choose **XSG** then install the market.
4. Right after the market installation, you cell will automatically hard reset itself and all of your data will be wiped.
5. Reboot your cellphone you will have your stock firmware all over again but with Google's market and that is it.

I've tried this before btw, and it worked just fine.